# Take the derivative of another variable

Tags: implicit-differentiation

How can you take the derivative

$$\frac{d}{dx}(y^2)$$

I don't understand how the chain rule applies here. Someone told me that the chain rule applies here because $y$ can be expressed in some type of $x$ expression, but I still don't get it.

So, I do understand how to apply the chain rule, I just don't understand why it applies in this situation.

I checked this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSVrqKZDRF4#t=200).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that by the [Chain Rule](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHBkQW_XuA4) you have $g(f(x)) = g'(f(x))f'(x)$. Now assuming $y(x)$ is a function of $x$ we have that

$$\frac{d}{dx} (y^2) = 2y\  \frac{dy}{dx} $$

Take $g(y) = y^2$ and $y = f(x)$.

Comment: I'll have a look at the video. The rest of the answer seems to state the same as in the video I linked.

Comment: He keeps on some examples, it's good to get the intuition.

Comment: I studied the video, and it's doing the exact same trick at 7:18. Somehow it's starting to make sense intuitively, but I can't explain it. I'm going to follow the rest of the series on implicit differentiation and see if it works out. I'll come back if I can't figure it out :p Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great that you are catching it. I'm glad I could help!

Comment: "Now assuming y(x) is a function of x" made me understand it properly now, because I tried thinking of how to differentiate the equation if y was any random x expression. I feel dumb now that I see how simple it is. Love it :)

Comment: Don't feel like that, it's part of the learning process. Keep up the good job!

Comment: One more thing: I understand how to get the derivative of $\frac{dy^2}{dx}$, but how did we know we must assume $y$ is a function of $x$? If it wasn't a function of x, then  $\frac{dy}{dx}$ would be $0$ (which would give a different result) according to Yves Daoust's answer (if I interpreted that correctly). So how can I tell by context that I have to assume this?

Comment: Yes you are right, if $y$ wasn't a function of $x$ then the derivative would be zero. This can be told when you are dealing with an implicit equation, implicit function, and context (exercise or theorem) will give you that.

Answer (score 3):

The chain rule always applies. You derive a function of $y$ (namely $y^2$) with respect to $x$, which is the same as deriving $y^2$ with respect to $y$ and multiplying by the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$.

$$\frac{dy^2}{dx}=\frac{dy^2}{dy}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=2y\frac{dy}{dx}.$$

Whether there is a dependency between $y$ and $x$ doesn't matter, the rule remains true.

If there is no dependency,

$$\frac{dy^2}{dx}=2y\frac{dy}{dx}=2y\cdot0.$$

Comment: the fact that y isnt explicitly defined in x confuses me :/

Comment: Does it help to express in the following?
$$\frac{d}{dx}y(x)^2 = 2y(x)\frac{d}{dx}y(x) = 2y(x)y'(x)$$

Comment: @jameselmore I'm just seeing the same formula as Yves stated, just with a different notation.

Comment: That's because it is. I was hoping to make the relationship between $y$ and $x$ just a little more 'explicit'

Answer (score 0):

$$
u(y) = y^2\\
y = f(x).
$$
Thus we have by chain rule 
$$
\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{du}{dy} = \frac{dy}{dx}\dfrac{d}{dy}y^2 = 2y'y
$$
So we have that 
$$
\frac{du}{dx} =\dfrac{d}{dx}y^2 =2y'y
$$

Answer (score 0):

I see this as differentiating with respect to $y$ and making up for it with a scale factor $\frac{dy}{dx}$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\{\}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d}{dy}\{\}$$

Hence:$$\frac{d}{dx}\{y^2\}=\frac{dy}{dx}\times 2y$$